# If Google services are banned in China, will Google Cloud Messaging and Google Analytics will work?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, great-firewall-of-china

I have an application with GCM and Google Analytic's implemented in it. I want to publish an app for all countries including China.

As China has blocked most of Google Services, my concern is that will GCM and Google Analytic's works in China?

Comment: I believe most devices in China don't have Google Play Servers or the Play Store, so GCM probably won't work for those.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to collect data for Chinese apps (and sites) through Google Analytics, I'm doing so myself.

As for GCM, I have no experience with that I'm afraid.